# Alternative to modprobe serial port

Tags: command-line, serial-port, embedded-linux, tty

I am working with a display that runs with a linux kernel.
I am trying to connect a device using serial communication to my display through a USB port.
To do this I am using a USB-serial converter.

When I am using the command `lsusb` I can see that my device is connected.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0557:2008 ATEN International Co., Ltd UC-232A Serial Port
```

The problem is that when my USB-serial converter is plugged I can't find my /dev/ttyUSB0 path.
I tried the command : `modprobe serialport  vendor=0x0557 product=0x2008` but it seems that the serialport module is not available on my display according to the answer I am receiving :

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module serialport not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.135-
```

Does anyone knows an alternative to `modprobe serialport` to get my converter recognized as a serial device ?

nb : My USB-Serial converter is a pl2303 converter and I am working with a 4.19.135 linux kernel.

Thank you,

Emmanuel

Comment: *"The problem is that when my USB-serial converter is plugged ..."* -- Use **dmesg** to obtain *all* messages after insertion.  The vendor&product numbers indicate a Prolific chip, i.e. a `pl2303 converter`.  Perhaps you simply do not have a kernel with the proper driver(s)?  Describe the kernel and board that you are using.